# Minimize Long text content display in PhpMyAdmin table

Tags: phpmyadmin

I have a content column in my table data and it is varchar type. I wonder is there a way to just show part of the content if it has long text like 2000 characters. I just don't want to see everything displayed in my row unless I want to click on it. Partial texts in option is checked by default. I am just hoping there is a way to reduce the height of my row.

[image]

[image]

Comment: "I hope there is a way to minimize the content that shows in my table in phpMyadmin" - So is this a phpMyAdmin question or a PHP, MySQL question?

Answer (score 2):

If it's a PHPMyadmin question. There is a link in its interface where you can limit how long is viewable of a column.

[image]

If my memory serves me correct it sometimes is labeled 'full texts' as well, which is also a link.

Comment: This just expands/reduces the width of row.

Comment: You may need to edit the contents (reduce newlines) directly as I can't think of any solution from PHPMyadmin itself for the problem you have.

Comment: Thank you very much anyway. I will live with the current state.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**:
Since this is about phpMyAdmin and not PHP and/or MySQL, then this is how you display less content/text in phpMyAdmin:

[image]

---

**This is how you replace multiple newlines into one:**

So you want to replace multiple newline's with just one? Just modify the input of the user before `INSERT`ing it to the database.

You can use [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php).

For example:

```
<?php

$val = 'test
test








test';

$val = preg_replace("/[\r\n]+/", "\n", $val);

// This is optional:
//$text = nl2br($text);

echo $val;
?>
```

Comment: I want to keep everything the user types in but I just don't want to see everything in my table data in phpMyadmin.

Comment: Wait. So your problem is how phpMyAdmin displays data?

Comment: @KevinVuD I edited my post. I will leave my previous answer just incase other people find it useful.

Comment: Just attach a picture after enable partial texts. Please see and let me know if you have better solution.

Answer (score -1):

Before entering the data into the database you can use the pre tag. Something like this `$description="<pre>" . $description . "</pre>";` Pre stands for preformatted text.